# What is the most useful way to document assessment of technological choices for a business problem?

Tags: templates, documentation

I would like to know if there are any templates for doing this in a clear and concise way to give the gist of the application and its inner workings and how it meets the business needs. I do not want to write a mythological story so looking for any new ways of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly this is about documenting what you actually need from the system.  You can't make a good choice if you don't know what you need.

[Here](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/enterprise-solutions/candidate-software-product-evaluation-template-30679) is a doc-style approach.

[This](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/302271/Decision-Matrix-Template) is a decision matrix approach outline.  The formatting is rough, but this is a good approach.  [This one](http://www.scribd.com/doc/7507112/Weighted-Decision-Matrix-) has better formatting, but is not about software (it doesn't really matter).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you are asking for, but [check out this paper](http://www.processgroup.com/pgpostoct05.pdf). It's a sample implementation of the CMMI's "Decision and Analysis Resolution" process area. It basically documents a method for comparing alternatives, reaching a decision, and documenting that decision.

The SEI's site has the [original definition of DAR](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/pub/documents/06.reports/pdf/06tr008.pdf) (see page 181), as well as a pretty [good presentation about it](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/cmmi/presentations/sepg04.presentations/dar.pdf). You have to realize that their whole goal is to help companies define their processes, not to push a particular process. So the documents you find there tend to be pretty high level, discussing the goals that your process should achieve and the specific practices that should be covered.

Comment: Chris, thanks for the link, do you happen to know a good source where it goes in detail on Decision and Analysis Resolution?

Comment: @CodeToGlory - I added some links to the Software Engineering Institute's website; they are the definitive source.

Answer (score 0):

Consult Eric Evans' "Domain Driven Design". At the end of the day, you're going to have to use your experience and judgment - and that of your team - to make the design decisions big and small, but Evans recommends formulating a one-page manifesto, written in business terms, to share with biz types that explains the value of your view of the domain to the business.